# nhibernate and virtual class properties?

Tags: .net, nhibernate

Just reading about nHibernate, why do the class properties have to be virtual?

What is the reasoning behind that?

Answer (score 21):

I would suggest you read [Must Everything Be Virtual With NHibernate?](http://web.archive.org/web/20090401144951/http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/)

> The quick answer to that question is:
>   because we need members to be virtual
>   in order to do our lazy loading
>   magic/voodoo.
>
> The longer answer is more interesting
>   though. An important feature that any
>   real ORM must have is transparent Lazy
>   Loading. If you retrieve an object
>   through an ORM, you don’t want it to
>   automatically pull in an entire object
>   graph (not by default anyway), yet you
>   don’t want to litter your code with
>   checks to see if certain associations
>   have been loaded yet, and then loading
>   them if necessary. This is the ORM’s
>   responsibility. Ideally, you want to
>   be able to access properties and have
>   the ORM load the necessary data upon
>   first access of those properties if
>   the data hasn’t been retrieved yet.

Answer (score 7):

As Andrew said, properties are virtual to trigger lazy loading. Here is an explanation as to why that is: At runtime NHibernate will substitute proxy objects for your real property objects. Once they are accessed, the proxy objects know how to get the real objects for you. Marking the properties as virtual allows this substitution to happen.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not using of the mentioned methods which are not virtual, you can simply add the `SetProperty` of the following snippet:

```
 NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseProxyValidator, Boolean.FalseString)
```

This simply turns off the validation causing the error, make sure you are not using non virtual methods as NHibernate will fail to proxy them (as suggested by the original error).